# How can I see the SQL statements which go to the database when using PDO?

Tags: php, debugging, pdo

How can I see the SQL statements which go to the database when using PDO?

Comment: You are using prepared statements and wonder if `WHERE x=:x AND y=:y` is somewhere "translated" to `WHERE x='abc' AND y='xyz'` and if you can inspect it?

Comment: exactly. that's one possible situation.

Comment: I just realized that my question is basically a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411182/how-to-debug-pdo-database-queries
Some good suggestions were left there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, enable the query log?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with bare PDO, but if you wrap PDO in a `Zend_Db_Adapter`, then you can use [Zend_Db_Profiler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html).

Then you'll be able to see the parameterized queries, together with the parameter values. Also, its *profiling*, i.e. measuring the query execution times.