# PHP PDO bug when trying to parameterize SQL LIMIT :offset, :display?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowcount

This query returns 5 results in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

And this returns count=12 in phpMyAdmin (which is fine, because there are 12 records):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

This function was working fine before I added the two variables (offset, display), however now it doesn't work, and printing the variables out gives me offset=0, display=5 (so still `LIMIT 0,5`).

```
function getProducts($offset, $display) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT ?,?;";
    $data = array((int)$offset, (int)$display);
    $rows = dbRowsCount($sql, $data);
logErrors("getProducts(".$offset.",".$display.") returned ".$rows." rows.");
    if ($rows > 0) {
        dbQuery($sql, $data);
        return dbFetchAll();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It's not working because my `dbRowsCount(...)` method was returning empty string (stupid `PDOStatement::fetchColumn`), so I changed it to return the count with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and it returns count=0.

Here is the function which does the row-count:

```
function dbRowsCount($sql, $data) {
    global $db, $query;
    $regex = '/^SELECT\s+(?:ALL\s+|DISTINCT\s+)?(?:.*?)\s+FROM\s+(.*)$/is';
    if (preg_match($regex, $sql, $output) > 0) {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM {$output[1]}");
logErrors("Regex output: "."SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM {$output[1]}");
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($data != null) $query->execute($data); else $query->execute();
        if (!$query) {
            echo "Oops! There was an error: PDOStatement returned false.";
            exit;
        }
        $result = $query->fetch();
        return (int)$result["count"];
    } else {
logErrors("Regex did not match: ".$sql);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My error log gives me this output from the program:

> Regex output: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT ?,?;
>   getProducts(0,5) returned 0 rows.

As you can see, the SQL has not been malformed, and the method input variables were 0 and 5 as expected.

Does anyone know what has gone wrong?

## Update

Following a suggestion, I did try to execute the query directly, and it returned the correct result:

```
function dbDebugTest() {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update LIMIT 0,5;");
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    $rows = (int)$result["count"];
    logErrors("dbDebugTest() returned rows=".$rows);
}
```

Output:

```
> dbDebugTest() returned rows=12
```

Following another suggestion, I changed !=null to !==null, and I also printed out the $data array:

```
logErrors("Data: ".implode(",",$data));
if ($data !== null) $query->execute($data); else $query->execute();
```

Output:

```
> Data: 0,5
```

**However, the dbRowsCount($sql, $data) still returns 0 rows for this query!**

## Update 2

Following advice to implement [a custom PDOStatement class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7716896/259457) which would allow me to output the query after the values have been binded, I found that the function would stop after $query->execute($data) and so the output would not be printed, although the custom class works for every other query in my program.

Updated code:

```
function dbRowsCount($sql, $data) {
    global $db, $query;
    $regex = '/^SELECT\s+(?:ALL\s+|DISTINCT\s+)?(?:.*?)\s+FROM\s+(.*)$/is';
    if (preg_match($regex, $sql, $output) > 0) {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM {$output[1]}");
logErrors("Regex output: "."SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM {$output[1]}");
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
logErrors("Data: ".implode(",",$data));
        $query->execute($data);
logErrors("queryString:".$query->queryString);
logErrors("_debugQuery():".$query->_debugQuery());
        if (!$query) {
            echo "Oops! There was an error: PDOStatement returned false.";
            exit;
        }
        $result = $query->fetch();
        return (int)$result["count"];
    } else {
logErrors("Regex did not match: ".$sql);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Output:

> Regex output: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product_category WHERE id=?;
>
>   Data: 5
>
>   queryString:SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product_category WHERE id=?;
>   _debugQuery():SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product_category WHERE id=?;
>
> Regex output: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT ?,?;
>   Data: 0,5
>   // function stopped and _debugQuery couldn't be output

## Update 3

Since I couldn't get the custom PDOStatement class to give me some output, I thought I'd rewrite the `getProducts(...)` class to bind the params with named placeholders instead.

```
function getProducts($offset, $display) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT :offset, :display;";
    $data = array(':offset'=>$offset, ':display'=>$display);
    $rows = dbRowsCount($sql, $data);
logErrors("getProducts(".$offset.",".$display.") returned ".$rows." rows.");
    if ($rows > 0) {
        dbQuery($sql, $data);
        return dbFetchAll();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Regex output: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT :offset, :display;
>   Data: 0,5
>   // Still crashes after $query->execute($data) and so `logErrors("getProducts(".$offset."...))` wasn't printed out

## Update 4

This dbDebugTest previously worked with declaring the limit values 0,5 directly in the SQL string. Now I've updated it to bind the parameters properly:

```
function dbDebugTest($offset, $display) {
    logErrors("Beginning dbDebugTest()");
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl_product WHERE 1 ORDER BY last_update LIMIT :offset,:display;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':display', $display, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $result = $stmt->fetch();
      $rows = (int)$result["count"];
      logErrors("dbDebugTest() returned rows=".$rows);
    } else {
      logErrors("dbDebugTest() failed!");
    }
}
```

The function crashes, and only this is output:

> Beginning dbDebugTest()

## Update 5

Following a suggestion to turn errors on (they are off by default), I did this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

That itself, made the dbDebugTest() from Update 4 work!

> Beginning dbDebugTest()
>   dbDebugTest() returned rows=12

And now an error is generated in my webserver logs:

> [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''0', '5'' at line 1'
>   in /home/linweb09/b/example.com-1050548206/user/my_program/database/dal.php:36

Line 36 refers to `dbRowsCount(...)` method and the line is `$query->execute($data)`.

So the other method `getProducts(...)` still doesn't work because it uses this method of binding the data and the params turn into ''0' and '5'' (is this a bug?). A bit annoying but I'll have to create a new method in my dal.php to allow myself to bind the params in the stricter way - with `bindParam`.

Thanks especially to @Travesty3 and @eggyal for their help!! Much, much appreciated.

Comment: did you try to run the query manually? like using `$db->query(xxx)` without any parameters or wrapper functions? does it work then?

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted? @kuba I didn't because I tried the SQL directly in phpMyAdmin and so I assumed it would work, but I will try that now.

Comment: @Ozzy: Nor do I understand the downvotes (you have my +1).  Have you tested the `if ($data != null)` to see which path the execution takes?  Shouldn't one use [`!is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) or `!==` in PHP?

Comment: @eggyal: Should probably be using [`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: kuba, yes that returns rows=12. I have a feeling the limit params aren't binding through the associative array. @eggyal I actually did try that and $data is not null p.s thanks for the upvote

Comment: @Ozzy: Perhaps try a wrapper class like [the one mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7716896/259457) in order to see the actual query that was run.

Comment: @Travesty3 is that the same as me printing the $sql statement I'm sending to the function which executes it?

Comment: @tereško did you have an answer? I can't seem to find whats wrong.

Comment: @Ozzy: The $sql statement still has the placeholder values `?,?`. Using the wrapper class, the aim is to get the actual query that is sent to MySQL, in order to verify that the placeholder values have been properly replaced.

Comment: @Travesty3 Ohh okay, so I guess I'll use that then let you know. Cheers.

Comment: @Travesty3 If I do it after $query->prepare it prints out the SQL with placeholders still in there, if I do it after $query->execute($data) it doesn't work/doesn't run for this query, but runs for all of my other queries... I've updated my question to add this info.

Comment: @Ozzy: I just posted an answer. Based on the fact that the script stops immediately after the `execute`, that hints that you are getting an error on the query, but are not actually seeing the error. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Update 2 in the question, where execution stops after the `execute` statement, it looks like the query is failing. After looking at [some PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), it looks like the default error handling setting is PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT, which would result in the behavior you are seeing.

This is most likely due to the numbers in your LIMIT clause being put into single-quotes when passed in as parameters, as was happening in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2269840/259457).

The solution to that post was to specify the parameters as integers, using the [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) method. So you will probably have to do something similar.

And it looks like you should also be executing your queries with try-catch blocks in order to catch the MySQL error.

---

bindValue method:

```
if ($data !== null)
{
    for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
        $query->bindValue($i+1, $data[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute($data);
}
else
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: I'm type-casting to (int) in my `getProducts(...)` method and besides which I'm doing it the same way for many other queries with integer values, and those work fine. I have to see `bindParam` if that works...

Comment: Yes, you are type-casting to int, but the trick is to tell *PDO* that the value is an int. To do that, you need to use PDO::PARAM_INT. To use that, you need to use the `bindValue` method.

Comment: Okay so I've tried it with the bindParam, type INT, and it still crashes. Please see my update.

Comment: @Ozzy: Did you try changing your error handling setting? Try `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`.

Comment: wow, that made the dbDebugTest() work! But the other method doesn't work, and an error is generated in my webserver log files, with a weird param input (it added an apostrophe)

Comment: @Ozzy: Did you switch to `bindValue` in your other method? I believe using `bindValue` with PDO::PARAM_INT will prevent PDO from surrounding the values with apostrophes, which would cause a MySQL error in the LIMIT clause.

Comment: No I haven't but I know, I'll have to change it. I'm a bit annoyed this doesn't work, because it works whenever I use it for other colums, its just with the LIMIT params that it fails (possibly because there are no columns, and it can't tell what the column type is). Thanks a LOT for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You're testing to see if `$data` is `NULL` with the equality, rather than the identity, operator (see [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information on how `NULL` values are handled by the various comparison operators).  You need to either use the identity test `===` / `!==`, or else call [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php).

As @Travesty3 mentioned above, to test whether an array is empty, use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: So thats a mistake, which I will now ammend. However, I did at one point print the the $data and it gave me "Array" so it is not null.

Comment: you are right, but I printed it outside of the IF clause, and just did it again now, its an array with values 0,5. I have a hunch this is to do with execute($data) not binding properly?

Comment: @eggyal: How did you determine that the test was failing? If it did take the `$query->execute();` path, then wouldn't MySQL throw an error if you tried to use `LIMIT ?,?`? (I'm actually asking, as I don't have much experience with PDO)

Comment: @eggyal Oh I agreed with you and changed it back then (when I said 'you are right'). I just updated my post to include the info.

Comment: @Travesty3: [The documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) is clear that loose equality comparison of an array with `NULL` is always `true` (and therefore `!=` is always `false`).  QED.

Comment: @eggyal I'm sorry if you misunderstood me, but when I said I updated my post to include the info, I actually meant, the info about changing that and it still not working! I'm still getting 0 rows returned

Comment: @eggyal I am using AS count!! And the dbDebugTest() worked! It's just when I'm binding the $data in `PDOStatement->execute($data)` that its not working. Please see the section in my question about `dbDebugTest()`

Comment: @eggyal the if ($data !== null) that one?

Comment: @eggyal I took out the clause completely, I did this:
`$query->execute($data)` without any clause, and it doesn't crash, it gives me 0 rows. Is there a chance PHP is binding them in the wrong order? So for example it would bind `LIMIT 5,0` and return 0 results? Nevermind just tested (1,5) and still got 0 rows.

Comment: Good call @eggyal. I didn't know that. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2269931/259457).

Comment: @Travesty3: That wasn't actually what I was thinking, but hey, if that solves it.. I don't think it should make any difference though, given that Ozzy has cast the array values to `int` on assigning them.

Comment: @eggyal: But perhaps the trick is to specify the value as PDO::PARAM_INT. For that, it looks like you may have to switch to the [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) method and use `PDO::PARAM_INT` as your third parameter.