# Issue escaping single quote on mssql 2008 from php codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I am doing an insert into a database where one of the columns that I am trying to escape are single quotes that a user might type. For example, `it's`,
I am using the codeigniter framework and did the following to escape my column:

```
$test=$this->db->escape($test);
```

But I get an SQL-Server error when I submit. For example if I type `it's`, its trying to do this

```
INSERT INTO table (test) VALUES(''it''s'')
```

When it should be

```
INSERT INTO table (test) VALUES('it''s')
```

Why is it inserting  extra single quotes?

Comment: Wouldn't the bottom one still be invalid?

Comment: Yes @LiamSorsby both are invalid , what it should do is this `'it\'s'` with the `\'`

Comment: when i run 'it''s' on the actual sql server it inserts fine when i run it with  'it\'s' its giving me an error

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yes I know that. I was just stating that the above answer says it should be the bottom one. Which is also invalid.

Comment: @LiamSorsby - Oh, it was formatted as a question.  Sorry

Comment: SQL Server escapes single quotes with '' NOT \'

Comment: In MSSQL the bottom is valid.

Comment: @LiamSorsby - seems we are both wrong.  I was thinking MySql, seems there are other databases out there.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yes, haha. Never used it and I new there were small differences however I wasn't aware that escaping like that was valid in MSSQL. It would be easier if there were just one standard.

Comment: Yeah, I am also used to writing on MySQL. There are definitely a lot of minor things that are different on MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are escaping your entire SQL statement when you should only be escaping the string you are inserting. For example, lets say you have the following code currently.

```
$test = "INSERT INTO table (test) VALUES ('" . $value . "');";
```

You should change it to be

```
$test = "INSERT INTO table (test) VALUES ('" . $this->db->escape($value) . "');";
```

---

### EDIT

As Liam pointed out, since you are using Codeigniter, you may want to also consider using the query binding they provide. See this URL for more information: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Comment: nice. I am going to try to do that

Comment: Great. Let me know if it works. I am far from a PHP expert so there might be an even more efficient way to do this :)

Comment: it works, thanks :) it makes sense. I will accept your answer when I am able to

Comment: @ShawnLehner Not entirely sure however would this not be a better way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156421/how-can-i-use-prepared-statements-in-codeigniter

Comment: Query binding is always the preferred method in any language but not required as long as you are properly escaping your variables manually.