# fetchall() does not work in Codeigniter 3 configured pdo driver

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I can't fetch result using PDO driver in Codeigniter3.

Configured pdo driver in config/database.php as below

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
```

...

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

...

```
  $query =
            "SELECT * FROM abc LIMIT 10";
            var_dump($this->db);

       $q=$this->db->query($query)->fetchAll();
```

but results in

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_result::fetchAll()
```

But if i try by creating PDO Object directly i can fetch data

```
$dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        try
        {
            $db = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
            echo "connected";

            $query =
                "SELECT * FROM abc ";

            $q=$db->query($query)->fetchAll();


            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($q);
            echo "</pre>";

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    }
```

What should i do to fix pdo configured in application/database.php?

Comment: Change  `'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db',` to  `'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db'`, and check

Comment: @Saty Thankyou for reply. i tried what you suggested but still same error

Comment: Have you set `'dbdriver' => 'pdo',`

Comment: there is no fetchall function afaik ?
just simply try to `$db->query($query)->result();`

Comment: @Saty I have set pdo as dbdriver

Comment: @sintakonte http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php fetchall() works when i manually instantiate pdo db object,please check last part of question . result() works with codeigniter pdo object

Comment: Dfriend's answer is a long version of my comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codeigniter database functions and Query Builder class do not have a function called `fetchAll`. Anytime you use `$this->db->...` you are using database class.

I recommend studying the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html).

Yes, if you can create and use a PDO object directly.

Comment: Thankyou for reply . If i want to use PDO directly , should i place  $db = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password); in every model class ? . Is that bad ? i am a newbie .

Comment: imho you should always use the Query Builder no matter what

Comment: @sintakonte can i define prepared statements with Query Builder? or i dont have to use prepared statement if i set pdodriver?

Comment: of course you can - just search for something like that (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156421/how-can-i-use-prepared-statements-in-codeigniter)

Comment: CI has a PDO driver. Read the docs and/or search SO for "[codeigniter]PDO" If you use the PDO driver you are still using the CI db classes and the associated methods.Direct calls to PDO functions won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a system database file called DB.php. Everyone seems to just modify (hack) it towards the end of the file. I've write a long bit of code for my personal PDO connection, but the below line is the basic idea.

```
$DB = new PDO($params['dbdriver'].':host='.$params['hostname'].';dbname='.$params['database'].';', $params['username'], $params['password']);
```

Comment out the section of code from:

file_exists($driver_file) OR show_error('Invalid DB driver');

to

$DB->initialize();

and then return $DB