# MySQL Query using UNION - PHP PDO issues

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have built a basic search engine which is almost functional. I am using `UNION` in the query in order to search for an specific value in two tables `blog` and `pages`. I am also using PDO style. There are a total of 13 rows. When I perform the query with keyword `blah` which is found in every column of both tables. I only get 5 results back from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog`  and nothing back from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages` . Also I am using a prepare statement for `:searchquery => $serachquery` that stores the keyword value but when echoing the value I get `:searchquery` instead of `blah`. How can I display the correct results? [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/search2.php)

PHP

```
<?php
include("db_con/db_con.php");
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
  $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
  if($_POST['filter1'] == "All Tables"){
   $sqlCommand = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE :searchquery OR blog_body LIKE :searchquery) UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE page_title LIKE :searchquery OR page_body LIKE :searchquery) ";
  }
  $sql_prepare = $db_con->prepare($sqlCommand);
  if($sql_prepare->execute( array("searchquery"=>'%'.$searchquery.'%') )){
    $count = $sql_prepare->fetchColumn();
    if($count > 1){
      $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    } else {
      $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong>$sqlCommand<hr />";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For:
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88">
Within:
<select name="filter1">
<option value="All Tables">All Tables</option>
</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** `UNION` **happened*** (*see a note below*) to give you in your case two rows in the resultset.

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|        5 | -- with fetchColumn() you read a value of only the first row
|        8 |
```

but you fetch only a value of the first row. That's why you always get `5` instead of `13`

**Note:** the usage of `UNION` in your particular case is **invalid** because it returns only distinct values. This means if both selects happened to have the same value (e.g. `5`) then your result set would've looked like this

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|        5 |
```

instead of

```
| COUNT(*) |
|----------|
|        5 | 
|        5 |
```

You might've used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` and either iterated over the resultset and got the sum in php, or used an outer `SELECT` with an aggregate function `SUM()`.

---

**Now** to get the total count you can simply do this

```sql
SELECT 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM blog 
         WHERE blog_title LIKE :searchquery 
            OR blog_body  LIKE :searchquery
) + 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM pages 
   WHERE page_title LIKE :searchquery
      OR page_body LIKE :searchquery
) total
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|    13 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65eed/3)** demo

---

Now as far as php code goes

1) this check

```
if($count > 1)...
```

is incorrect and actually useless since you can legitimately get only one hit by your search criteria and `COUNT()` always return a value be it `0` or some other positive integer. Therefore you can simply leave the only line

```
$search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
                                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2) You see placeholders `:search query` when you output the query because you output the raw sql query from `$sqlCommand` variable.

Comment: Now it makes more sense! to why i was getting only one result set

Comment: *how could i display the values the query is showing?* Here is a good generic solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716785/get-last-executed-query-in-php-pdo

Comment: In this particular case (for this specific query) it can be just a strait forward `str_replace`. Take a look at this [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L3tnIF) example

Comment: Great but I meant how to display the query results. The data from the tables?

Comment: Got it. That is where `UNION ALL` comes to play. See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65eed/8) example. Then you iterate over the resultset and render your search results.

Comment: alright great, so would i need to run two sets of queries. 1st set to count the number of values and 2nd set to get the results? Also in the php would i need to do foreach loop to echo the results right?

Comment: There is no need two issue two queries. You can for example use `fetchAll()` and use `count()` to get the number of rows in the resultset that will be returned as an array. Yes `foreach` would be the most convenient way to iterate over the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

now replace this line :

```
$count = $sql_prepare->fetchColumn();
```

with this :

```
$count = 0;
foreach($sql_prepare->fetchall() as $records)
{
    $count += $records[0];
}
```

it returns count of all rows;

Answer (score 0):

I made a sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82482/3

As you see your query returns two rows - this might be your problem.
You can enhance your query to sum the both results:

```
SELECT SUM(results)
FROM 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) as results
      FROM blog 
      WHERE blog_title LIKE '%blah%' OR blog_body LIKE '%blah%' 
      UNION
      SELECT COUNT(*) as results
      FROM pages 
      WHERE page_title LIKE '%blah%' OR page_body LIKE '%blah%') a
```