# Is the leading colon for parameter names passed to PDOStatement::bindParam() optional?

Tags: php, pdo

When passing named parameters of the form `:name` to [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), it seems to work whether or not the leading colon is used.

i.e. either this:

```
$statement->bindParam(':name', $var);
```

or this:

```
$statement->bindParam('name', $var);
```

seems to work.

Here's the documentation for [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

> **parameter**
>
> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named
>   placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form *:name.* For a
>   prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
>   1-indexed position of the parameter.

Does this mean the colon can be left off?

Comment: I'd say the colon is needed in the SQL expression, but not when you name (identify) the name with `bindParam`. The PDO function is probably less strict here as it can define it's own interface to name the parameter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, since the documentation doesn't mention this I think it's safe to assume that this behaviour isn't officially supported and shouldn't be relied upon.

However, it does actually happen to work (in PHP 5.3.24 at least) - internally a colon will be added to the parameter if it's missing ([see `ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c:363` in the PHP 5.3.24 source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3.24/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363)).

Comment: I was wondering about the same question. My guess was that : is used to strictly diferentiate colName with sql keywords. It's good to know that PDO will fix missing : in bindings. I'll take hakre's advice and keep : in sql statements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591519/php-pdo-using-bindparam-first-argument-without-colon/71920041#71920041