# What does it mean the colon in queries yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I'm totally new in yii2 and I want to know what does it mean the colon in the query?

I have made a research about binding parameters, but in the yii2 documentation says:

```
// returns all inactive customers
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE status=:status';
```

which side is from the data base? the left side or the right side?

which is a simple text and which one is a column from the DB? Im so confused.

what would be another way to make the query without the colon? is it valid?

why it has `'anyo = **:**valor'` in the next example? and some others dont?

```
$dbLibro = Libro::find()->where('tipo = "Nacimiento"')->andWhere('cerrado = 0')->andWhere('anyo = :valor',[':valor'=>date("Y")])->one();
```

I hope its clear cause the documentation is a bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 4):

The colons are not directly related with Yii2, it's related with [PHP PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that used by Yii2.

Each colon is placeholder used later for binding value. Check for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/php-prepared-statement-what-are-parameter-colons-used-for).

If we write this query in `ActiveQuery`:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE status = :status
```

we can get something like this:

```
$query = Customer::find()->where('status = :status', [':status' => Customer::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
```

Assuming `STATUS_ACTIVE` constant equals to `1`, after execution it transforms to this:

```
SELECT * FROM "customer" WHERE status = 1
```

So the left side (before equals) represents column name, right part - value which will be safely binded after.

But you don't have to write params by yourself, Yii2 `QueryBuilder` generates it automatically for you.

There are other ways to write query without colons and they are used more often. This query can be written like this:

```
$query = Customer::find(['status' => Customer::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
$models = $query->all();
```

Or like this using shortcut:

```
$models = Customer::findAll(['status' => Customer::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
```

Or it can be even put inside of a [scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes):

```
$models = Customer::find()->active();
```

In this case Yii generates parameters automatically and it will be equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM "customer" WHERE "status"=:qp1
```

Value `1` will be binded to `:qp1` parameter, note that in this case column names are also double quoted.

If you try to use more conditions, params will be `:qp2`, `:qp3` and so on (default `PARAM_PREFIX` is `:qp`).

As for your second query, it can be rewritten like this:

```
$model = Libro::find()
    ->where([
        'tipo' => 'Nacimiento',
        'cerrado' => 0,
        'anyo' => date('Y'),
    ])->one();
```

Such queries look way better and readable in this state.

Yii2 allows generate even more complex conditions in queries, check [this section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail) of the docs for more details.

**P.S.** It's better to use english for naming in your code. Think about other international developers supporting your code. `date('Y')` can be calculated using database functions depending on used RDBMS.