# Yii2 bind param to the raw sql statement for the IN field

Tags: sql, yii2, dao

When I'm using bindParam in the Yii2:

```
$arr = [1,3];
$str = implode(' ,', $arr);
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('DELETE FROM article_tag WHERE article_id=:id AND tag_id IN (:str)')
        ->bindValue(':id', $this->id)
        ->bindValue(':str', $str)
        ->execute();
```

if I bind str to the IN field , the raw sql seems to becomes

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1 ,3'
The SQL being executed was: DELETE FROM article_tag WHERE article_id=13 AND tag_id IN ('1 ,3')
```

and it tells me the incorrect double value here. I guess it's because it adds single quotes to the sql . How could I deal with this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can be refactored to:

```
Yii::$app
    ->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->delete('article_tag', ['article_id' => $this->id, 'tag_id' => $arr])
    ->execute();
```

Use framework features, writing raw SQL is needed for more complex queries.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622344/what-does-it-mean-the-colon-in-queries-yii2-framework) to understand how params are automatically binded.
[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail) you can see how to specify condition to where statement.

For most cases it's better to create `ActiveRecord` and use `ActiveQuery` for building queries.

Comment: will it delete multiple record here? I use IN cause I want to delete multiple record using one sql.

Comment: @tyan Yes, when you pass an array as a value to key-value pair in `where` statement, it will be automatically converted to `IN` statement. See [provided link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail), there is an example with array and `IN`.