# limit doesn't work with ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have some problems with the limit using active record.

I've created a dataProvider with a limit of 5:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Devicesdb::find()
            ->joinWith('score')
            ->where('devices.devicetype = :deviceType', [':deviceType' => $device])
            ->orderBy(['score' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(5),
        'totalCount' => 5,
    ]);
```

And this is the resultant query in debug panel:

```
SELECT `devicesdb`.* 
FROM `devicesdb` 
LEFT JOIN `devices` 
ON `devicesdb`.`id` = `devices`.`id` 
WHERE devices.devicetype = 'phone' 
ORDER BY `score` 
DESC LIMIT 20
```

The query is fine , and retourns me the data as I want, but I only want 5 items, not 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `totalCount` is a property of [Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html), not [ActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html). You need to nest it inside of a pagination configurational array. But this is not how you achieve this.

Because you don't want the pagination to appear you can disable it by passing `false` and now limit will be taken from query (otherwise it's ignored and calculated differently, you can see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748211/limit-is-not-working-in-activedataprovider)):

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Devicesdb::find()
        ->joinWith('score')
        ->where('devices.devicetype = :deviceType', [':deviceType' => $device])
        ->orderBy(['score' => SORT_DESC])
        ->limit(5),
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);
]);
```

One more thing - you don't have to write params manually, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622344/what-does-it-mean-the-colon-in-queries-yii2-framework) for explanation and better understanding. So `where` part of the query can be reduced to just:

```
->where(['devices.devicetype' => $device])
```

Also I recommend to refactor model name to just `Device` and use this to resolve duplicate names conflicts (if any) in SQL query:

```
->where(Device::tableName() . 'devicetype' => $device])
```

That way if this model related table name will changed in the future, you don't have to refactor your code.

Comment: But totalcount is a property of ActiveDataProvider i used to hide the the pagination bar. Anywhere I've tryed your code and doesn't work. Query still retourning 20 items.

Comment: @Sageth I corrected the answer with more detailed explanation, check it.

Comment: i've found a pretty simple solution thanks to you to give me and idea :D, check it, I want to know your opinion.

Comment: @Sageth Sorry, I missed something. Corrected the answer once again, please check it. And by the way you can post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to question.

Comment: I've posted the edit before saw your edit, and your code is smarter, thanks :D

Comment: @Sageth I checked your solution, I suggested something similar before. But this doesn't hide the pagination bar in case of amount of models larger than limit (5).