# PHP: Array declaration and named variable

Tags: php, arrays

What is the deference between `array('hi'=>$hello)` and `array(':hi'=>$hello)`

I am using the second form to `insert` my data using `prepare` statement by extending `PDO` which is working fine. However when I change array declaration to first form `array('hi'=>$hello)` no data is being inserted, I was wondering how they both work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP prepared statement - what are parameter colon's used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/php-prepared-statement-what-are-parameter-colons-used-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`':hi'` is a named variable and also an index/key in your array this can pass values to your database (Used in PDO).

`'hi'` is just an index/key in your array

Answer (score 0):

Your first example:

```
array('hi' => $hello);
```

creates a key called '`hi`', and your second example creates a key `:hi`. To use PDO parameters you need to prepend the parameters with a colon. The colon is used to designate and identify the parameters.
See [PDO prepared statement - what are colons in parameter names used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/php-prepared-statement-what-are-parameter-colons-used-for)