# How would one skip empty field values when submitting a form using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that echoes values for a specific user from a MySQL database using PHP. I am trying to figure out how to allow the user to submit the form to update their user information but have the form skip any field they have no filled out.

**Current update statement**

```
if (!isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {
    $db = DB();
    $stmt = "UPDATE users SET fName = :fName, 
                              lName = :lName, 
                              emailAddress = :emailAddress 
                              WHERE user_id = $user->user_id";
    $query = $db->prepare($stmt);
    $query->bindParam(':fName', $_POST['fName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':lName', $_POST['lName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':emailAddress', $_POST['emailAddress'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
};
```

**Form echoing user information**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="profile.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fName" placeholder="<?php echo $user->fName ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lName" placeholder="<?php echo $user->lName ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="<?php echo $user->emailAddress?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top: 7px;">
                        <?php echo $user->username ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="btnUpdate" value="Save Changes" type="button">
                        <span></span>
                        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Currently this doesnt appear to update the database at all. If I leave the form completely blank and submit it, the values that existed in the database are now empty. i.e., just blank columns.

I have been looking at other examples on how to do this but I cannot seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Just to be sure I am in fact updating the correct user, I made sure that my `$user->user_id` statement is in fact returning the correct user_id from the database for the update.

**UPDATE**

Currently this is how I have the update statement / code

```
if(!empty(['btnUpdate'])) {
$stmt = "UPDATE users SET fName = IF(:fName = '', fName, :fName), 
                lName = IF(:lName = '', lName, :lName), 
                emailAddress = IF(:emailAddress = '', emailAddress, :emailAddress)
        WHERE user_id = $user->user_id";
$db = DB();
$query = $db->prepare($stmt);
$query->bindParam("fName", $fName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam("lName", $lName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam("emailAddress", $emailAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
}
```

Using `<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>` returns 0 after submitting the form and I still end up with empty database columns

Comment: `$_POST['$fName']` is a typo on the name. You also should bind the `$user->user_id`. If `$fName` is set that should be unquoted or in double quotes.

Comment: Im not sure I completely understand your comment. I see the typo on the fName. If I am simply grabbing the user_id and not submitting it, should I need to bind it?

Comment: There are other typos in your code, too: your named placeholders, when used in `bindParam()`, must have a `:` at the start, i.e. `$query->bindParam(':lName'...)`. The way you are referencing objects in your `$_POST` object is also incorrect: `$_POST['$fName']` should be `$_POST['fName']` instead, for example.

Comment: @Terry it's not necessary any more.

Comment: I have updated the OP. Outside of this however, what logic would you use in PHP to ignore blank fields so the columns arent updated?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It is not officially documented, so I would say we go on the safe side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778887/is-the-leading-colon-for-parameter-names-passed-to-pdostatementbindparam-opt.

Comment: You will need to build the query dynamically. Use the `empty` function (unless `0` is a valid value for some of your fields). You should bind everywhere, don't put variables in queries.

Comment: @Terry/Paul For `:` or not topic see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/pdo-prepared-statement-what-are-colons-in-parameter-names-used-for.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't ignoring empty fields, but a more user friendly solution would be to stick the database values into each input's `value` attribute. That way, you don't have to skip the fields if they're blank, and a user won't get confused when editing their data. If you don't want them to be able to edit the value, just include the `readonly` attribute.

If you don't want to do this, than you could either create a dynamic query or use an if statement to decide which value to use, the form's or the database's.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the query check whether the value is empty, and reuse the existing value.

```
$stmt = "UPDATE users SET fName = IF(:fName = '', fName, :fName), 
                          lName = IF(:lName = '', lName, :lName), 
                          emailAddress = IF(:emailAddress = '', emailAddress, :emailAddress)
                          WHERE user_id = $user->user_id";
```

You could also build the query and parameters dynamically.

```
$sets = array();
$params = array();
foreach (array('fName', 'lName', 'emailAddress') as $field) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $sets[] = "$field = :$field";
        $params[":$field"] = $_POST['field'];
    }
}
if (!empty($sets)) {
    $sets_string = implode(', ', $sets)
    $stmt = "UPDATE users SET $sets_string WHERE user_id = :id";
    $params[":id"] = $user->user_id;
    $query = $db->prepare($stmt);
    $query->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: I assume I should be setting the value of each input based on the current value in the database?

Comment: It looks like you're already doing that. If they don't modify the field, they'll just set it to the same value, which shouldn't be a problem. Why would you need to skip anything?

Comment: Im not 100% sure what I am doing wrong here. I tried going the query check route, but when I submit my form, I still end up with blank values showing up in the database.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what the actual post values are.

Comment: It is returning 0

Comment: That makes no sense, `$_POST` should be an array. Sounds like you have a bug somewhere that's overwriting the variable.