# PDO SQL I'm trying to set my SQL query to check multiple columns but it is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have built a login system where I check if the user exists using either their username or their email address.

This is my code:

```
// DB Connection Included
$q = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (username=:e OR email=:e)");
$q->execute(array('e'=>$user));
```

But it doesn't work. It works perfectly if I change the query to:

```
$q = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=:e)");
```

or

```
$q = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE email=:e)");
```

I've used this code before and it has always worked perfectly, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work this time.

The actual error I get is a validation error in my code. I check to see if the user exists using the rowCount() function; using the desired query, rowCount() returns 0.

I have also tried:

```
$q = $dbcon->prepare("SET @user = :user SELECT * FROM table WHERE (username=@user OR email=@user)");
```

This was suggested on another post I found on Google, but this also did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need the brackets around the where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`PDO::Prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to
>   pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You
>   cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in
>   a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

So try -

```
$q = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (username=:e1 OR email=:e2)");
$q->execute(array(':e1'=>$user,':e2'=>$user));
```

Comment: @PrateikDarji semicolons in the `prepare()` are required, but optional in `execute()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386503/689579 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925175/689579

Comment: @PrateikDarji it can only be done with one parameter, if as the docs state - *unless emulation mode is on*. So if the OP did `$dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);`, it would work

Comment: This worked. However, I have used the code that I provided (i.e. used the same parameter marker) on a different site that I built, and it worked fine. So I still don't understand why it worked then, but doesn't now. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy its possible that the other site had `emulation mode` on by default.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll try to remember to consider that in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Looks okay to me except for the parentheses.  Try ...

```
$q = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=:e OR email=:e");
```

Comment: *except for the parentheses*, are you saying that MySQL actually cares whether you put those parentheses or not? It really doesn't, but I personally think the query looks better without them. This can be a suggestion, but not an answer.

Comment: Using different parameter names solved my problem, however, I did adopt your method and have removed the parentheses. Thanks for your suggestion.