# How a placeholder in a prepared statement calls a value in an associative array?

Tags: php, prepared-statement, associative-array, placeholder

The code is already working, but I couldn't fully understand how the place-holders is calling the value of an associative array. I already read the documentation but without success to understand it.

```
$app['dtb'] -> insert('users', [
    'name' => $_POST['name']
    'age' => $_POST['age],  ]);`
```

My insert method:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    'insert into %s (%s) values (%s)',
    $table,
    implode(', ' , array_keys($parameters)),
    ':' . implode(', :' , array_keys($parameters))
);
```

So this would result on something like this:

```
insert into users (name) values (:name)
```

If i'm not using any `bind_param` how it identify that `:name` is the value of the key `name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_param` is a `mysqli` function. That driver does not support named placeholders. You must be using `PDO`, `PDO` has a `bindparam` function that is similar. It also allows you to just pass an array to the `execute` function. This binds the values in the order they appear if unnamed placeholders were used (`?`), or by the keys of the array if the placeholders were named (`:...`). I'd guess you are passing `$parameters` to the `execute` function.

Comment: I'm ussing PDO and I'm passing $parameters to the execute function, you are right. But I still didn't get how it get by the `:name` that it is the value, not the key.

Comment: It is the key of the array. `['name'  => $_POST['name']` so `:name` is replaced with `$_POST['name']`'s value and escaped. The `:` is optional for the array's index. If not present PDO auto adds it.

Comment: Here's another thread on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925175/3783243, see the section that starts with `This means that the parser can safely assume`

Comment: It's almost clear now, I'll take it for grant that in this structure the colons will indicate to replace for the value of that corresponded key, in this case `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: You can prove the theory by breaking it, add an `s` to one of the keys and you should get an error about the number of parameters/placeholders.

Comment: It really helped.