# PDO prepared statements binding

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement

i have a data array e.g. this:

```
$data = ['ver_weather' => $post["weathercondition"],
         'ver_flash'   => $post["flashintense"],
         'ver_earth'   => $post["earthrumble"]]
```

these data i use in my sql like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`weather`, `flash`, `earth`)
        VALUES (:ver_weather, :ver_flash, :ver_eart)";

$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
```

The result is something like:

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`weather`, 'flash', `earth')
VALUES ('1'weather, '1'flash, '1'earth)
```

So is pdo replacing parts of my keys with the value ?

what is wrong there ?

thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: Execute does work with named bindings so you could just edit your $data array like this:

```
$data = [':ver_weather' => $post["weathercondition"],
         ':ver_flash'   => $post["flashintense"],
         ':ver_earth'   => $post["earthrumble"]]
```

Note the : at the beginning of each key

Original answer below...

I think the issue is that you're trying to bind by name and I don't think PDOStatement supports named bindings. I'd recommend trying the following:

```
$data = [$post["weathercondition"], $post["flashintense"], $post["earthrumble"]];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`weather`, `flash`, `earth`)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
```

Comment: I'm fairly positive that you don't need the `:` in the key of the array. I'm not sure where OP's problem is coming from, but it isn't that. ([More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/pdo-prepared-statement-what-are-colons-in-parameter-names-used-for))