# php PDO update multiple records at a time

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to update mulitple records at a time with pdo. When i execute the script no error shows up, but the records in the database not get updated

```
require_once('../connect.php');
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$collective_answer=($data->answers);
$sme_id=($data->sme_id);

foreach ((array) $collective_answer as $t) {
    $answer= $t ->answer;
    $quest_id= $t ->quest_id;
    $sme_id= $t ->sme_id;
    $tdate= $t ->tdate;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE sme 
                SET sme_answer=:sme_answer,
                    date_answer_sme=:date_answer_sme
                WHERE question_id=:question_id");

    $stmt->execute(array("sme_answer" => $answer,
                         "date_answer_sme" => $tdate,
                         "question_id" => $quest_id));
}
```

Comment: 'sme_answer' (etc.) should be ':sme_answer'

Comment: Did you check error reporting was set ON

Comment: Maybe it would help to see a `print_r($collective_answer);`

Comment: And did you set [ATTR_ERRMODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648371/my-pdo-statement-doesnt-work) on the PDO Connection

Comment: @treyBake - they are optional in the `execute()` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/pdo-prepared-statement-what-are-colons-in-parameter-names-used-for

Comment: You should move the `prepare()` outside the loop as this is only required to be run once.

Comment: @NigelRen hot damn! Learn something new everyday