# PHP PDO Check if row exist with two WHERE Condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to look for the text exist in the row inside the table called website.

Where `uid` is INT and `domain` is String.

If the Row is found and both `uid` and `domain` matches. It should output `success`.

If the Row Value doesn't exist, it should output `nothing`

Both `UID` and `domain` are giving by the user in input form.

With the below code, It's not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM website WHERE uid=:uid AND domain=:domain');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['uid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_GET['domain'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row)
{
    echo "found";
}
else {
    echo "nothing";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bindParam()`, the first parameter is the bind point.  From the manual

> Parameter identifier. **For a prepared statement using named
> placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name**. For a
> prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
> 1-indexed position of the parameter.
> (emphasis mine).

As you use named parameters in your SQL, you should use...

```
$stmt->bindParam('uid', $_GET['uid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

etc.

(Not sure if there is a duplicate for this, will remove if one is found).

Comment: You're missing the colon in the placeholder.

Comment: @El_Vanja, the colon is optional https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/pdo-prepared-statement-what-are-colons-in-parameter-names-used-for