# PHP PDO using bindParam first argument without colon

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

check this please

```
  $user_id = (int)$_GET['user_id'];
  $sql = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id';
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam('user_id',$user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $delete = $query->execute();
```

actually it is wokring prperly and it deletes the user row from database

but the question here is that i didn't write ':' that column in the bind query
i mean

this should be wrong

```
$query->bindParam('user_id',$user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

this should be correct

```
$query->bindParam(':user_id',$user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

but it doesn't throw any exception and the user row is being deleted successfully

any explaination about this ?

Comment: in the query there is :user_id ..it should be $user_id $sql = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=$user_id';

Comment: mmmm do you have any idea about bindparam ?

Comment: Check out this post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778887/is-the-leading-colon-for-parameter-names-passed-to-pdostatementbindparam-opt

Comment: Thanks buddy , if you just put it in separated answer to be accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post explains why the use of the colon is needed.

[Is the leading colon for parameter names passed to PDOStatement::bindParam() optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778887/is-the-leading-colon-for-parameter-names-passed-to-pdostatementbindparam-opt)

From the post:

> No, since the documentation doesn't mention this I think it's safe to
>   assume that this behaviour isn't officially supported and shouldn't be
>   relied upon.
>
> However, it does actually happen to work (in PHP 5.3.24 at least) -
>   internally a colon will be added to the parameter if it's missing (see
>   ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c:363 in the PHP 5.3.24 source code).

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know but I just came across this information in the PHP Documentation for PDO (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

In the examples, it shows two ways to bind a value to a parameter, either with a colon or without it.

It even explicitly states that they are optional:

> /* Names can be prefixed with colons ":" too (optional) */

From testing on PHP 7.4.28 I can confirm that using with or without a colon works when using `->bindValue` and when passing an associative array directly into `->execute(...)`

I'm not sure if this has always been there or when it was added, but as of now it seems that either way is fine.

Comment: This is quite [recent](https://github.com/php/doc-en/commit/65d4ecb42e75a180eb8964968c230b09d81d3601)

Comment: @YourCommonSense nice find, wasn't sure where to find this info but good to know!