# PDO prepare and execution of query returns always error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, prepare

I have a function,

that returns to me always a mistake, even if in the phpmyadmin when I past the query there is a result.

I guess there is something wrong in my query but I don't know what. I used to do my code doing mysql_real_escape_string, then I turn to PDO, they told me I should do a prepare for escaping GET vars, so I tried do do it.

Below is my query

```
public static function getDetailService($param) {
    global $bdd;
    $detail = $bdd->prepare('SELECT
            spb_services.spb_services__name,
            spb_services.spb_services__description,
            spb_services.spb_services__banner,
            spb_services.spb_services__tabs,
            spb_services.spb_services__category
        FROM spb_services
        WHERE spb_services.spb_services__name LIKE :service');

    $detail->bindValue(':service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $resultat = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //var_dump($_GET[$param]);

    $detail->debugDumpParams();
    $lignes = $detail->fetchColumn();

    //var_dump($lignes);
    $detail = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $retour = ($lignes > 0) ? array('status' => 'ok') : array('status' => 'error');
    var_dump($retour);
}
```

When I call the function : `$service = nosServices::getDetailService('service');`

Var dump of `var_dump($_GET[$param])` return to me what expected (from the url)

Then I did `$detail->debugDumpParams();`

I past the query in my localhost phpmyadmin, it returns to me what expected but not when using PDO.

I guess a small things is wrong bu tI have no idea what.

This returns no mistakes, but always error, as if there is no `num_rows_result`

To sum up the trouble, the GEt returns what expected, but when we go to the query, it return no result (except in my phpmyadmin copy and paste the query)

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Edit : modifications done as expected by other users

Comment: `":service"` remove the double quotes here. In `bindValue` add `:` before `service`

Comment: I have still a mistake

Comment: it still does not work :
SQL: [270] SELECT spb_services.spb_services__name, spb_services.spb_services__description, spb_services.spb_services__banner, spb_services.spb_services__tabs, spb_services.spb_services__category FROM spb_services WHERE spb_services.spb_services__name LIKE :service Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :service paramno=-1 name=[8] ":service" is_param=1 param_type=2

Comment: what return $detail->debugDumpParams(); ?

Comment: SQL: [270] SELECT spb_services.spb_services__name, spb_services.spb_services__description, spb_services.spb_services__banner, spb_services.spb_services__tabs, spb_services.spb_services__category FROM spb_services WHERE spb_services.spb_services__name LIKE :service Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :service paramno=-1 name=[8] ":service" is_param=1 param_type=2

Comment: you are missing `$detail->execute()`. you need to execute query before fetchAll

Comment: people get the misconception about the colon in binds, it's only required in the values. Read for yourselves http://stackoverflow.com/q/9778887/

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski You need to check for errors here. So use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php to see if anything comes of it, besides you're not executing the query.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski *"as if there is no `num_rows_result`"* - What exactly do you mean by that? If that's part of code you're not showing and if that is a `mysqli_` function, then we need to know. If it is a `mysqli_` function, those different APIs do not intermix with each other. You are connecting with PDO, right?

Comment: yes I'm using pdo only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of strange things happening in your code.

I have commented where I think things need to change

```
public static function getDetailService($param) {
    global $bdd;    // bad practice, see later suggestion
    $detail = $bdd->prepare('SELECT
                     spb_services.spb_services__name,
                     spb_services.spb_services__description,
                     spb_services.spb_services__banner,
                     spb_services.spb_services__tabs,
                     spb_services.spb_services__category
                FROM spb_services
                WHERE spb_services.spb_services__name LIKE :service');

    // $GET? I assume you want to use the `$param you pass as a param to this function
    //$detail->bindValue(':service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // a LIKE normally requires a string like '%something%'
    // or 'something%'
    // DO we assume you passed $param with the wildcards already applied?
    $detail->bindValue(':service', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // now the prepared query must be executed
    $detail->execute();

    // fetchAll returns ALL the result set into an array
    $resultat = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // as you are using a LIKE we have to assume there will be more 
    // than one row returned. 

    // fetchColumn makes no sense here
    //$lignes = $detail->fetchColumn();

    // You already did a fetchAll so this makes no sence
    //$detail = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // as all you appear to be doing is testing if one or more rows are returned
    // then all you need to do is coumt the occurances in the $resultat array

    $retour = (count($resultat) > 0) ? array('status' => 'ok') : array('status' => 'error');

    // Now you need to return something
    return $retour;

}
```

> It is also bad practice to use a `global` in a class method as it breaks the encapsulation, it is better practice to pass something like that as a parameter.

EG This

```
public static function getDetailService($param) {
    global $bdd;
```

Becomes this

```
public static function getDetailService($bdd, $param) {
    // global $bdd;   <-- no longer needed
```

Or if it is needed throughout the class then make it a class property!

> If I am right and all you want to know from this method is if something exists, a `SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt` would be a more efficient way of doing that, but lets leave that for another day as it would also chnage how you get at the result and write the rest of this code
>
> Final Note: You are doing no error checking after any of the PDO statement taht could possibly go wrong. Almost all of these PDO statements return a status that if false you should display yourself a PDO generated error message See [ErrorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: you are really helpfull, thank you for all the advice and thank you to everybody for having taking the tipme to answer me. I would have to check all answer as satisfy but this one was the most complete, and solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter binding needs to be corrected.

You are missing `:` while providing value to parameter.

Corrected code:

```
...
WHERE spb_services.spb_services__name LIKE  :service');
        $detail->bindValue(':service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did this but I still have no results

Comment: Well first,the OP has to remove some quotes.

Comment: I did this to remove the quote

Comment: Colon isn't the issue, driver auto appends that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778887/is-the-leading-colon-for-parameter-names-passed-to-pdostatementbindparam-opt (follow source code link) Placeholders don't get quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Only issue in your code Forget to execute query before fetching data It would be

```
 $detail->bindValue(':service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $detail->execute();// execute it first
 $resultat = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 print_r($resultat);
```

Comment: I did all the modification but it still does not work, I guess I'm wrong somewhere else

Comment: I did `$detail->bindValue(':service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $detail->execute(); // execute it first
        $lignes = $detail->fetchColumn();
        $resultat = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($_GET[$param]);
//        $detail->debugDumpParams();
//var_dump($lignes);
        $retour = ($lignes > 0) ? array('status' => 'ok') : array('status' => 'error');
        var_dump($retour);` And I have a error

Comment: colon isn't required in the bind, just values, here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9778887/

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski still you are not executeing  query before fetching data

Comment: I tried this ` $detail->bindValue('service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $detail->execute(); // execute it first
        $lignes = $detail->fetchColumn();
        $resultat = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` but I still have error

Comment: no errors display, only there is no result, but when I paste the query in php my admin it works

Comment: it is like if the bind value is not applicated to the query

Comment: Try with `$keyword = "%".$_GET[$param]."%";  $detail->bindValue(':service', $keyword , PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: ANd please check `$_GET[$param]` have a value!!

Comment: the get param var_dump return string 'demolition' (length=10) I paste your code, it does not work still. When I replace manualy thevalue of get param to the query I paste it on phpmyadmin it works. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: _Only issue in your code_ I think you missed a few things old chap

Comment: what is that old chap ?

Comment: check updated four line use it in your code and post the value of `print_r($resultat);` if you get it!!

Comment: I have array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Also follow the steps of  `RiggerFolly's` answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to do $detail->execute(); To process the SQL request

```
$detail->bindValue(':service', $_GET[$param], PDO::PARAM_STR);
if( ! $detail->execute()) {
   die('Invalid Mysql Query!');
}
$resultat = $detail->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Bit late to the party there buddy