# PHP - PDO Prepared statment, "Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at least 2 parameters"

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, execute, bindparam

i am trying to use a prepared statement to set a placeholder value using a class object property that is passed as an argument to the __construct function. However i seam to be getting an error specifying the need for 2 parameters when i only have one parameter for the place holder value.

**CODE:**

```
<?php include ('connection.inc.php');

class Team {

    // Remember to switch back to private!
    private $database;
    public $statement = 'SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY :full_name';
    public $order;
    public $query;

    private $result;    

    public function __construct($database, $order) {
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->query = $this->database->prepare($this->statement);
        $this->query->bindParam(array('full_name', $this->order));
        $this->query->execute();                
    }

    public function getMember() {        
        $this->result = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $this->result;                        
    }
    public function id() {
        echo $this->result['id'];
    }

    public function fullName() {
        echo $this->result['full_name'];
    }
    public function alias() {
        echo $this->result['alias'];
    }
    public function abilities() {
        echo $this->result['abilities'];
    }    

};

$test = new Team($database, 'full_name');

?>
```

**ERRORS:**

**Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in**

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'**

**Solution**

Thanks to @Daerik, i changed my `bindParam()` statements to:

```
$this->query->bindParam(':full_name', $this->order));
```

This removed the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable  )

`$parameter`: Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.

`$variable`: Name of the PHP variable to bind to the SQL statement parameter.

You'll want to use:

```
$this->query->bindParam(':full_name', $this->order);
```

For more information read [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Thanks, that removed both errors and. However when iterating of the sql query using the `gettMember()` method it seams to ignore my `ORDER BY ':full_name'` statement and used the `id` column to sort the entries. Is this a fault in my prepared statement?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers You'll want to use a column in the `ORDER BY` statement. Assigning a string will compare them all to the same value and default to the index. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html for more information.

Comment: thank you will read through it and make the necessary adjustments!

Comment: after some reading it occurs to me that the string i am passing to the placeholder is in fact the name of the column. Is this wrong?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers That is correct. The placeholder is used for values and not columns.

Comment: thanks! I did some research found that can simply store the string value of the column in question as a property of my class and build the query string using that property. Worked beautifully. Now i can pass any column name as a string value to the class construct and it does exactly what i want!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `bindParam()` to pass multiple parameters, just use:

```
$this->query->execute(array(':full_name' => $this->order));
```

Note: You need to include the `:` in the parameter name and you need to pass `':key' => $value` pairs.

Or for just one, don't pass an array, `bindParam()` requires two arguments:

```
$this->query->bindParam(':full_name', $this->order);
```

Comment: You don't have to include `:` when using `PDOStatement::execute`.

Comment: @Daerik:  Never tried it and all manual examples show `:parameter`, also _The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL._, but it may be possible.

Comment: Colons are required in the SQL statement, to indicate which identifiers are placeholders. Colons in the `execute()` calls are optional. The documentation specifies them, but the implementation is clever enough to figure out what you mean if you leave them out.

Comment: @Daerik You wrote *"Colons in the execute() calls are optional."* - In some very rare instances, colons are required in the bind. However, in your answer, you seem to be contradicting your comment. I originally saw that question earlier and was going to suggest they include the colon but I did not since I didn't think that was the issue, since and again; is very rare that the colon needs to be used and it's even documented https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3.24/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363 as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9778890/1415724 the real problem was the use of `array`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the documentation. At the time I was answering the question, I was solely basing it via the manual, as in my experience I prefer `execute()`. It was not until later, after looking for resources to support my claim, that I came to understanding that it works for `bindParam()` as well. No point editing an answer to reflect a comment made on another answer. I wonder if the behavior is not officially supported, how come it adds the `:` when it's missing.

Comment: @Daerik You're welcome. Well, it is rather strange that their manual doesn't make any mention of it and I agree with you. In regards as to why the colon is required in some rare cases and if it's documented, I have yet to find that out; might be "Goblins" hehe. But yeah, it is rare that the colon is required and could be based on their version of php and/or db collation, hard to say really. And no, no point in editing.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, thank you for replying to my question i ended up giving Daerik the answer but your answer as well as the comments below were educational.