# PDO fetch returning zero

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code which i am testing from last couple of hour but unable to understand that why `TodayAttendanceCount`  is not returning 0.

```
    $sqlCheckLoginEntryCount = "SELECT Count(*) TodayAttendanceCount FROM AttendanceMachineLogin
                                WHERE Date(RecordAddDateTime) = :RecordAddDateTime
                                AND TimeTrackId = :TimeTrackId";

   $statementEntryCount = $connPDO->prepare($sqlCheckLoginEntryCount);

   $queryParams = array(
        ':TimeTrackId'          =>    $TimeTrackId,
        ':RecordAddDateTime'    =>    $RecordAddDateTime
    );

   $statementEntryCount->execute($queryParams);

   $queryData = $statementEntryCount->fetch();

   echo '\n ';
   //var_dump($queryData);
   echo "\n Attendance Count". $queryData['TodayAttendanceCount'] ." ;";
```

I have executed the same query in MySqlWorkbench which is working fine and there is data and it is fine from the database side.

Comment: I did but this didn't make any difference

Comment: I think everything was ok, you have to run sql directly in phpmyadmin check what results you are getting

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @whoami Yeah i have already done this as i mentioned in the question. It is working fine.

Comment: Are you simply missing the `AS`, shouldn't it be `SELECT Count(*) AS TodayAttendanceCount` in your query?

Comment: Can you add what you get from `TodayAttendanceCount` if not `0`? And how did that `var_dump` look?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:` part at the `$queryParams`. It isn't needed. The code will look like this.

```
$queryParams = array(
    'TimeTrackId'          =>    $TimeTrackId,
    'RecordAddDateTime'    =>    $RecordAddDateTime
);
```

Comment: no the problem still persist. I have done many query with colon. it doesn't make any difference

Comment: what about this? $queryData->TodayAttendanceCount

Comment: This is not write, throwing exception as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    $sqlCheckLoginEntryCount = "SELECT Count(*) As TodayAttendanceCount FROM AttendanceMachineLogin
                                WHERE Date(RecordAddDateTime) = ':RecordAddDateTime'
                                AND TimeTrackId = :TimeTrackId";

   $statementEntryCount = $connPDO->prepare($sqlCheckLoginEntryCount);

   $queryParams = array(
        'TimeTrackId'          =>    $TimeTrackId,
        'RecordAddDateTime'    =>    $RecordAddDateTime
    );

   $statementEntryCount->execute($queryParams);

   $queryData = $statementEntryCount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   echo '\n ';
   //var_dump($queryData);
   echo "\n Attendance Count ". $queryData['TodayAttendanceCount'];
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: An explanation of what you've changed and how this should solve the problem would help.

Comment: @NigelRen the `SQL` query misses the `As` keyword. The array of the desired values shouldn't have preceding colons in the array keys.

Comment: `as` is optional in MySQL, also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778887/is-the-leading-colon-for-parameter-names-passed-to-pdostatementbindparam-opt

Comment: but we shouldn't rely on this behaviour and in the official documentation the colons are ommited.

Comment: I'm in favour of not using undocumented features, but there is a difference between something that happens to work (but shouldn't) and something that doesn't work at all.  As such although it's good to change it - will it solve OP's problem?

Comment: good point, but, that's why we have "best practices" in the programming/programmers industry. So, we should, only, rely on official documentations. The OP may or may not be helped out with that but these points "will" help another person, let me say: if you know something good share it !