# Parsing HTML tags to PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My code is Parsing HTML tags using regex and store all the links as an array inside the data base

**I have a problem in my code i don't know how to fix it to save the links inside MySQL**

i see this error message
Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $domain = "https://google.com";
    $input = @file_get_contents($domain) or die("Could not access file: $domain");
    $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
    if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $url=$match[2];
            // $match[2] = link address
            // $match[3] = link text
        }
    }   
    $rows = array($domain, $url);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO linkss(id, domain, url) 
                            VALUES (NULL, :domain, :url)");
    foreach($rows as $key => $value){
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    $stmt -> execute();  
    echo "New records created successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are passing the data to the prepared statement is incorrect, you using the index to the array - which is a 0 based numerically indexed array.  This is why you get the error.  Although not sure why you need this array...

```
$rows = array($domain, $url);
```

Instead I would suggest using...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO linkss(id, domain, url) 
                          VALUES (NULL, :domain, :url)");
foreach($url as $value){
     $stmt->bindParam(':domain', $domain);
     $stmt->bindParam(':url', $value);
     $stmt -> execute();  
}
```

This should also insert a record for each URL rather than the last one as the `execute()` is inside the loop.

**Update:**

You also need to amend the code which builds the list of URL's, this was previously overwriting the last URL all the time, this will create a list of all of the URLs...

```
$url = array();
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $url[]=$match[2];
}
```

Comment: i removed $rows = array($domain, $url); and used your code but i see now another error  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ddd/public_html/links.php on line 27

Answer (score 0):

When binding the parameter you need to specify the `:` in the parameter name:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':' . $search_field, $search_val);
```

You are getting an error because this is missing and the code falls back to expecting an integer value to indicate the parameter position (as if you were using ?-style parameters).

Note this description of the first parameter for PDOStatement::bindParam() from the documentation.

> **Parameters**
>
> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named
>   placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a
>   prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
>   1-indexed position of the parameter.

Comment: That's optional and not the problem here.

Comment: You need to specify the `:` otherwise it won't recognize the parameter

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778887/is-the-leading-colon-for-parameter-names-passed-to-pdostatementbindparam-opt

Comment: That's just wrong. Named placeholders can be specified without colon.

Comment: Didn't knew, me is always told to add the colon