# How can ignore the second and third array when there is no data?

Tags: php, html

I have below code on my page and I am displaying dynamically field.

```
<input type="file" name="pic[1]"   class="work_pic">
<input type="text" name="title[1]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="desc[1]"  class="form-control">


<input type="file" name="pic[2]"   class="work_pic">
<input type="text" name="title[2]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="desc[2]"  class="form-control">


<input type="file" name="pic[3]"   class="work_pic">
<input type="text" name="title[3]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="desc[3]"  class="form-control">
```

Below is my logic code

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];
foreach($title as $key =>$value){ 
    $ogimage=$_FILES['pic']['name'][$key];
    //print_r($ogimage);
    $work_pic =" ";
    $work_dir = "assets/images/uploads/pic/";
    $filename1  = basename($ogimage);
    $extension1 = pathinfo($filename1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $newrand        = mt_rand();// random number
    $work_pic       = $newrand.'.'.$extension1;
    $target_file = $work_dir . $work_pic;
    $uploadOk = 1;

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $errorMsg[]="Sorry, your file was not uploaded dynamic.";
        $code="5";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"][$key], $target_file)) {
            $workimagename= $work_pic;
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    $insert_array = array(
              'title' => $title[$key],
              'desc' => $desc[$key],
              'pic' => $workimagename,
              'user_id' => $lastUserid,
          );
      
    $sqlwork="INSERT INTO `tbl_abcwork`
                    (`title`, `desc`, `pic`, `user_id`) 
            VALUES (:title,:desc,:pic,:user_id)";
    $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sqlwork);
    $stmt->execute($insert_array);
```

My logic is working perfectly if I filled all three with data. I am getting the output

```
Array ( 
    [title] => testing 
    [desc] => testing 
    [pic] => 1756775265.png 
    [user_id] => 6
   ) 
  Array (
   [title] => testing 
   [desc] => testing 
   [pic] => 869702765.png
    [user_id] => 6 
  )
  Array (
     [title] => testing 
     [desc] => testing 
     [pic] => 1145700947.png 
     [user_id] => 6 
   )
```

If I filled data only in the first fieldset then I am getting output.

```
Array ( 
  [work_title] => alndlasd 
  [work_year] => lknalksndlaksd 
  [work_pic] => 1332366488.png 
  [user_id] => 7 
) Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Array ( 
  [work_title] => 
  [work_year] => 
  [work_pic] => 1332366488.png 
  [user_id] => 7 
) Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
Array ( 
  [work_title] => 
  [work_year] => 
  [work_pic] => 1332366488.png 
  [user_id] => 7
   )
```

I am getting the data in my database.

[image]

Issues

1. I am getting the same image in 2 and third array
2. How can ignore the 2 and 3 array when there is no data?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: have you tried to clean up (remove empty elements) your 'source' array using `$title=array_filter($_POST['title']);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Apologize for my bad code, I'll not repeat this in future.

Comment: @jibsteroos, I haven't tried array_filter as of now. Let me check this.

Comment: I'm surprised that the query inserts anything at all. You work with named parameters (`:title,:desk,:pic,:user_id`) but your array keys miss the colon.

Comment: @Michel its sorta-allow to not include the colon on keys, its implied. It makes code more confusing to look at yes, and shouldnt be relied on, but it still works behind the scenes (for now).

Comment: @IncredibleHat Mmm, never knew that. And manual doesn't mention it. Makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @Michel Just saw this... so yeah, prolly not a good idea to do it :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778890/2960971

Comment: @IncredibleHat, So Do I need to add colon in bind param?

Comment: @user9437856 The `$insert_array` keynames would be better off having the colon in them, just to be safe and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried by using if?

```
if (!empty($title) and !empty($desc)) {
//foreach
  if (!empty($_FILES['pic']['name'][$key])) {
  //save
}
//endforeach
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid answering a question, with a question :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting all 3 images with the same name in your database because `$insert_array['pic']` is being set to `$workimagename`, which is only being set on successful saving. When your first image saves, `$workimagename` is being set, and inserted, and then in subsequent loops you're not resetting its value anywhere.

Scoping in a `for` loop doesn't work quite how you'd expect. For example, if after the `for` loop you tried to use any variable declared inside the loop (i.e. `$uploadOk`) you would still be able to get the value from the last iteration of the loop. My first recommendation is at the beginning of the loop do `$workimagename = '';` at the very least to reset that value.

But your second issue should be easily fixed with a conditional to verify all data exists before trying to upload the image:

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) { //will this ever be true?
    $errorMsg[]="Sorry, your file was not uploaded dynamic.";
    $code="5";
} else {
    if ($value) { //this should check if any value exists for this input
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"][$key], $target_file)) {
            $workimagename= $work_pic;
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Image was not provided";
    }
}
```

Maybe instead of checking `if ($value)` you should check `if ($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"][$key])` instead. I don't fully remember how PHP handles file uploads like this, but if you check for the existence of the input data before trying to do anything with it, it will allow you to skip over non-existent inputs.