# Force PHP to display full MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

When your query is not correct, php returns an error message like following one:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@aaa.com)' at line 1' in C:\Program Files\...
```

Is there a way to force it to  display full MySQL query string in error message?

**Update**:

I need a solution that works in entire web site (in development stage).

Perhaps via php.ini of my.ini

I currently use ZF for database interaction.

Comment: maybe you could look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411182/how-to-debug-pdo-database-queries

Comment: die(mysql_error().$sql);

Comment: I don't know. But what about mysql_error()? It doesn't return the sql sentence, but it could be helpful.

Comment: Note that such detailed error messages are only meant for the developers and should not be shown in production.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = /* PDOStatement */
if (!$stmt->execute()) {

    echo $stmt->queryString;
}
```

Comment: is a member variable of PDOStatement, generated by it's execute method. just use it, it's there ;)