# Match pattern, but not returning all of it

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty new to regex. Say that I have a string like so:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column = :column WHERE column IN(:column_32, :column_34, :column_347)
```

And then assume that I have an array:

```
$arr = array(
    'column' => 'Test',
    'column_32' => 'Tester',
    'column_34' => 'Faux data',
    'column_347' => 'Column data'
);
```

What I want to do is replace the placeholders (:column, :column_32 etc) with their corresponding values in the array. Problem is, str_replace wont cut it as replacing :column with 'Test' will result in :column_32 becoming :Test_32 etc.

So, I've started writing some custom regex. Here's a test script I've been running:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    var_dump(preg_match_all('(:'.$v.'[^_])', $str, $matches));
}
```

It matches the correct strings. Problem is, it also returns "," and ")" as a part of the match. Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: This is exactly what `bindParam()` does in PHP's `PDO`. [See here; especially Example #1.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) It's just odd because the `:xyz` syntax hints that your code used such a `bind` implementation to begin with, and now you seem to want to hack it via regex...

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the wheel (aka. PDO prepared statements)?

Comment: @acheong87 Writing a PDO wrapper class that automatically creates, prepares and executes prepared statements using an associative array. I'm replacing the placeholders with their corresponding values for debug purposes.

Comment: Have you looked at the PDO `debugDumpParams` method? http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php  See also this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411182/how-to-debug-pdo-database-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are avoiding all the non `_` chars after your keyword. `[^_]` after your variable means "find a single char that is not an underscore", thus your regex correctly grabs the comma and the closing parenthesys.

Why don't you just try to find the identifiers? Searching for `:column_347` for example would be fine. You may want to search for a word boundary after your placeholder to tell your regex "don't stop if this (eg column) is not a whole word.

This is obtained replacing the `[^_]` with `\b` which is a word boundary. [This link](http://rubular.com/r/s3pOMn3E9r) shows how this works, note that the regex matches only the first "column"

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit of a hack, but how about you order your array by key length from longest to shortest. Then any key that can be a substring of another key will be checked after its containing string. So you reorder your array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'column_347' => 'Column data'
    'column_32' => 'Tester',
    'column_34' => 'Faux data',
    'column' => 'Test',
);
```

You can, of course, also do this automatically. As of PHP 5.3.0 like this:

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if(strlen($a) > strlen($b))
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
});
```

Below 5.3.0 you could either use this (as of PHP 4.0.1):

```
uksort($arr, create_function('$a, $b', '
    if(strlen($a) > strlen($b))
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
'));
```

Or (which is maybe preferable, if you cannot use the nice anonymous function syntax, or if you use PHP before 4.0.1):

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    if(strlen($a) > strlen($b))
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

uksort($arr, "compare");
```

Comment: I like this solution, simply because it gets rid of the need for regex.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your regex question, but I wanted to offer the `PDO` implementation anyway:

```
<?php

    $sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET column = :column WHERE column IN(:column_32, :column_34, :column_347)'

    $arr = array(
        'column' => 'Test',
        'column_32' => 'Tester',
        'column_34' => 'Faux data',
        'column_347' => 'Column data'
    );

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $sth->bindParam(':' . $k, $v);
    }

    $sth->execute();

?>
```

If you are working with someone else's code and weren't aware of `PDO`, then this is probably the right way to go, for many reasons (including protection against injection attacks). However, if you're aware of `PDO` and desire an alternate, regex-based implementation anyway, then @m.buettner and @Gabber both provide sound advice.

Comment: @WtotheX - Sorry, I did not see your comment while posting this answer. So you're not only aware of `PDO` but actually _enhancing_ it; cool. I'll leave this answer up in case there _are_ others who are reinventing the wheel and might stumble upon this question.