# How to run a PDO prepared statement (with named placeholders) in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

Gone are the days when I did something like this: 
`WHERE something = '".$query->real_escape_string($your_unsafe_value_here)."'`

So I've made the move to prepared statements, but I'm a little confused on how to debug some of my queries now. Here's an example PDO prepared statement that uses named placeholders. I've taken this from the online php manual:

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
                      FROM fruit
                      WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

If I need to do a quick test on a query, how do I run something like this in **phpmyadmin**? (...or is there another mysql GUI that can easily handle these types of queries?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411182/how-to-debug-pdo-database-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my setup this is what I ended up doing. Hopefully this solution will help someone else, regardless of my setup details...

**1)** I turned on query logging in my `my.ini` file (I'm using Windows / WAMP):

```
[mysqld]

log = "C:\wamp\logs\queries.log"
```

**2)** I needed to tell PDO to [emulate prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) (I'm using Laravel 4.1):

```
// Before you run the query...
 $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
 $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , true);    
// run query here...
// and then die, so it's the last query ran
die();
```

**3)** Keep the *queries.log* file open in notepad++ and just reload the file when prompted by notepad++. Copy & paste the last query into phpmyadmin. Now I can debug the query!

I'll probably later have to come up with a more automated approach, but this seems to work  for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run the Query in Toad for MySQL.. When you run the query you get a pop-up to enter the variables

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PDO queries in phpMyAdmin directly and I don't know any other programs that can do that. You can build your own by writing the code from a form to a file and excuting that code in de background. But that isn't very safe because you can run anything there