# inserting mutltiple form data via php into multiple mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

Still very new to php but learning quickly. I have two forms that gather data that is then passed to a php function. All the data from both forms is making it to the php file as I am echoing the values to be sure.

My issue is the first table is updated correctly without any issues but the second table is not updated.

Here is the code in question

```
private function registerNewUser($user_name, $user_email, $user_password, $user_password_repeat, $captcha, $user_type, $first_name)
....

// write new users data into database
    $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, user_type) VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), :user_type)');                
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_type', $user_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);                
    $query_new_user_insert->execute();              

// id of new user
    $id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

    echo $first_name;
    echo $user_email;
    echo $id;
//  attempt at writing to additional table
    $this->db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    $query_new_user_insert2 = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO C_Customer (First_Name, Email_Address, Created_Date, id) VALUES(:first_name, :user_email, now() :id');
    $query_new_user_insert2->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_new_user_insert2->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query_new_user_insert2->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_new_user_insert2->execute();
```

`$query_new_user_insert` works as the table is updated

`$query_new_user_insert2` does not work as the table `C_Customers` contains no data.

Comment: You should do some research about debugging PDO queries. You could start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411182/how-to-debug-pdo-database-queries

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion as I now see the error. I updated the above code to show what it looks like now. When I now run this I get the following error (the value of 53 is the id from the users table which is correct )
`Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''53''`. The line that this is erroring out on is the `$query_new_user_insert2->execute();`

Comment: You have your `:id` parameter outside your "values" parenthesis in that second query. Voting to close as simple typo. Please make sure you have error handling around all your DB access.  You would have seen that syntax error you noted and likely fixed the problem in shorter time than it took you to write up this post.

Comment: Wow.. how embarrassing.. I fixed that ( thank you @MikeBrant ) however I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second query, you forgot to put comma between `now()` and `:id`. Also, you forgot to put closing bracket.

```
prepare('INSERT INTO C_Customer (First_Name, Email_Address, Created_Date, id) VALUES(:first_name, :user_email, now() :id')
```

should be

```
prepare('INSERT INTO C_Customer (First_Name, Email_Address, Created_Date, id) VALUES(:first_name, :user_email, now(), :id)');
```

Another typo :) hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you !!. that was it. I guess I need to walk away for a bit as I am making to many typo's.. I cannot mark your answer as correct as I do not have reputation to do so. But this solve my issue.